# How to retrieve past Github GPG keys?

Tags: git, gnupg, github

Github's public GPG key very recently (2024-01-16) expired.

I have deleted my locally stored public key copy of that key and cannot verify old commits of our repo.

Now to retrieve the Github public GPG key you can download it from:  https://github.com/web-flow.gpg

Unfortunately there is no way to download the expired key from Github directly.

How could we do that?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that you can download the past key using Way Back Machine here:
https://web.archive.org/web/https://github.com/web-flow.gpg

You can go back in time as you want.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.